# Throw error in error function of $http causes $digest already in progress in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Here is a plunker showing the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/J8zRIj?p=preview

Here is a plunker with the error commented out in both the scripts.js and scripts.spec.js and I don't get the $digest error anymore:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jCRlwf?p=preview

Throwing and testing for errors seems to work when they are not inside a callback of an $http request.  Anyone know why this might not be working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the mock $exceptionHandler service re-throws exceptions by default. So your exception is causing a $rootScope.$apply to be aborted in the middle.

One solution is to switch the mock $exceptionHandlerProvider to 'log' mode and then check $exceptionHandler.errors. [See here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZGw6pd?p=preview).

Comment: What about errors that throw exceptions like this : http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1pxSJ?p=preview : in this case .errors is an array with a empty object?

Comment: That's just Jasmine's pretty printer making it look like an empty object... it's really your Error instance. See http://plnkr.co/edit/fvAcB5?p=preview.